# Not able to remove first comma in string SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The code works fine except for

```
SELECT DISTINCT isnull(@FEATURE + ', ', ',') + Feature 
    FROM [128.100.194.219, 1435].[EMSData].[dbo].[vOSLRoomFeatures] as rf2 where (rf2.roomid =   rf.roomid)
    for xml path('')),
```

which is giving me problems. I do not know how to get rid of the first comma. I have tried substring but it removes all the commas(I guess since it's in a select statement). I even tried 
*COALESCE(@FEATURE + ', ', '') + FEATURE* but I end up with the same result, either no commas or one extra comma at the end or at the very beginning.

```
DECLARE @FEATURE VARCHAR(500) 
-- INSERT INTO BookableRooms IF NOT EXISTS ROOM NUMBER 
INSERT INTO dbo.BookableRooms_test (FK_Building_code,
                                    Room_num,Other_room_name,
                                    Capacity_from,
                                    Capacity_to,
                                    Accessiblity,AV_book_separate,Flooring_type,Features,
                                    Food_drink_allowed, Alcohol_allowed,Internet,
                                    [Owner],FK_BookingContact_ID,
                                    LCD_projector,Computer,FK_SpaceManager_code,Last_updated_date,Last_updated_by,SpecialFlag)
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
            WHEN rf.[Building Reference] is null or rf.[Building Reference] = '' THEN 'HH'
            ELSE rf.[Building Reference] 
        END,
        [ROOMID],[Description],
       (SELECT MIN(rf2.CAPACITY) FROM [128.100.194.219, 1435].[EMSData].[dbo].[vOSLRoomFeatures] AS rf2 WHERE rf2.ROOMID = rf.ROOMID),
       (SELECT MAX(rf2.CAPACITY) FROM [128.100.194.219, 1435].[EMSData].[dbo].[vOSLRoomFeatures] AS rf2 WHERE rf2.ROOMID = rf.ROOMID),  
       dbo.iszero([Wheelchair Accessible]), dbo.iszero(rf.[Separate AV]),dbo.isflat(rf.[Flat Floor]),
       (
        SELECT DISTINCT isnull(@FEATURE + ', ', ',') + Feature 
        FROM [128.100.194.219, 1435].[EMSData].[dbo].[vOSLRoomFeatures] as rf2 where (rf2.roomid = rf.roomid)
        for xml path('')),
       dbo.iszero(rf.[Food and Drink]),dbo.iszero(rf.[Alcohol]),dbo.iszero(rf.[Room Internet]),
       'HH',5,
       dbo.iszero(rf.[Digital Projector]),dbo.iszero(rf.[Computer]),'HH',GetDate(),'System',dbo.iszero(rf.[Restricted])

 FROM [128.100.194.219, 1435].[EMSData].[dbo].[vOSLRoomFeatures] as rf  where NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.BookableRooms_test b WHERE 
    b.Room_num = rf.ROOMID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Stuff but on the outer side of subquery:

```
stuff ((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Feature 
        FROM [128.100.194.219, 1435].[EMSData].[dbo].[vOSLRoomFeatures] as rf2 
        WHERE (rf2.roomid = rf.roomid)
        for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to remove the leading comma.

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF(',' + Feature 
    FROM [128.100.194.219, 1435].[EMSData].[dbo].[vOSLRoomFeatures] as rf2 where (rf2.roomid =   rf.roomid)
    for xml path('')),1,1,''),
```

Comment: Thank you Joe for the 'stuff command' it's just that one comma gave me errors and I picked Markovinovic's answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If my guess was wrong, it would good if you told us what results you expect in which situation.

Try this

```
CASE WHEN @FEATURE IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @FEATURE + ', ' END
```